# Proving that an analytic function on a connected set which includes the upper half plane and satisfies a certain inequality is of a certain form

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f$ be an analytic function on a connected open set $X$ which includes the closed upper half plane $\bar{\mathbb{H}}=\{z \in \mathbb{C};Im(z)\geq0\}$. Suppose there exist positive real numbers $M$ and $\delta$ s.t. $$|f(z)|\leq \frac{M}{(|z|+1)^{\delta}}$$
for all $z$ $\in \bar{H}$. Show that 
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t-z}dt$$
for all $z$ $\in \mathbb{H}=\{z \in \mathbb{C};Im(z)>0\}.$

How would I go about proving this? I'm quite stuck. I feel like $f$ must be a constant, and I would like to use the Maximum Principle to prove that, but I don't see how that's supposed to help me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint: Use the Cauchy integral theorem to write
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(t)}{t - z} \, dt$$
where $C$ is a closed semicircular contour of radius $R$ centered at the origin. Examine the behavior as $R \rightarrow \infty$.

Edit: To address your original idea, it is not true that $f$ will be constant. For example, consider $f = 1/(z + 2)$. It's true that $f$ decays at $\infty$, but since it is not entire it doesn't contradict Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the hint and for showing me the error of my original idea. If I let $R \rightarrow \infty$, then $C$ will become the boundary of $\mathbb{H}$, correct? Then the Cauchy Integral Theorem gives me the result, since $f$ is analytic, the integral over the contour will be 0 and what's left will be the integral over the real line?

What bothers me is that I don't see why the inequality regarding the absolute value of $f(z)$ on the closed upper half plane matters in this problem (Assuming I understood your hint fully of course).

-A

Comment: You have to use the inequality to show that the half-circle portion (the part in the upper half plane) of the contour integral reduces to $0$ as $R \rightarrow \infty$.